# Accessing subattributes in WFS with FE?

Tags: wfs, filter

I have a WFS server that I need to filter information out of with filter encoding. If the attributes are on the surface, I don't have any problems getting their information. But I don't know how to get the information if it is a subfeature.

In the example below, I would use:

```
<fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  <fes:ValueReference>app:dørtype</fes:ValueReference>
  <fes:Literal>Slagdør ut</fes:Literal>
</fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

to get all with that value, but I don't know how I would get "app:rampeLengde" under "app:Rampe".

[image]